# Is it possible to use puppeteer to compare a screenshot with the ui elements of a webpage and find differences?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I am looking for any documentation or help with this. Right now for testing whether UI elements appear on the screen I just check if that class or ID is loaded, for things like the login form, title, logo, submit button, input fields, etc.

I thought I remember seeing Puppeteer could help with analyzing a screenshot and then loading the webpage and comparing the two, but I could be way off.

Also for anyone who use Puppeteer, what's the best way to verify UI elements load on a webpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Puppeteer to take a screenshot and then use something like,
https://github.com/uber-archive/image-diff  or https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick to [compare two images](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20761&start=15).

Comment: You can capture the image and use ImageMagick compare on two same sized images. See https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/